# Why is urlencode not working when posting message in Arabic via Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, urlencode, arabic

$message is retrieved from mysql db

The db  tables have utf8_general_ci as character encoding

The following is executed with each connection:

```
mysqli_query($this->link,"set character set utf-8");
```

The php file is encoded utf-8

```
$message=urlencode($message);
```

When the following command is used:

```
echo $response = file_get_contents
("https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sendMessage?chat_id=-100xxxxxxx&disable_web_page_preview=TRUE&parse_mode=markdown&text=". $message);
}
```

If  retrieved $message is stored in English: it works

If $message is stored in Arabic:  it **doesn't** work

If $message is entered in Arabic in the file itself (not retrieved from db):  it works

What is wrong?  I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to config your MySQL DB character-set manually using phpMyadmin
set it to "utf8"
or programmatically when opening your connection try this code:

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db"); 
    mysqli_query($dbcon, "set character_set_server='utf8'");        
    mysqli_query($dbcon, "set names 'utf8'");
```

you may need to check the messages in the DB tables and may need
to re-enter your msgs to the DB again if it's misformatted because of the wrong char-set.

Comment: Thanks, but both are already set (set character_set_server='utf8' + set names 'utf8'.  I tried several things directly on the db - no success!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the reason is that the browser still treats $message as "WINDOWS-256" encoded.  Everything else is UTF8 encoded!

So iconv resolved the issue.

```
$message=urlencode($message);
```

Should be:

```
$message=urlencode(iconv("WINDOWS-256", "UTF-8", $message));
```

I don't really know why, but it has done the trick!